# Time discrepancy between data in logfiles and timestamp in corresponding filenames

Tags: java, log4j2

I switched from `log4j` using a property file, to using xml and finally to `log4j2`,
because I wanted timestamps on the log files.

```
    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="log/${name}.log"
        filePattern="log/${name}-%d{dd-MM-yyyy_HH.mm.ss}.log">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="${pattern}" />

        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy>false</OnStartupTriggeringPolicy>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" /> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>

    </RollingFile>
```

My problem is that the timestamps on the files are to 'new' for their content, because of the logging mechanics, i. e. after each run of my program a file `${name}.log` is written, if there already is a file with given name, a file `log/${name}-%d{dd-MM-yyyy_HH.mm.ss}.log` is
created and the content of the former file is copied into it. Then `${name}.log` is overwritten with logging information of the current run.

So there is always a discrepancy between the content of the timestamped log files and the time given in their name.

**Question**

Is is possible to fix this issue? And if it is, what do  I have to configure?

---

**Example**

name.log : contains data from second run

```
19-07-2013 13:10:58.462 [main] INFO  main.App (App.java:60) 
Trying to print string!

19-07-2013 13:10:58.467 [main] INFO  main.App (App.java:61) 
Be aware!

19-07-2013 13:10:58.467 [main] INFO  main.App (App.java:63) 
String printed

19-07-2013 13:10:58.467 [main] DEBUG main.App (App.java:64) 
Program executed!
```

name-19-07-2013_*13.10.58*.log : contains data from first run

```
19-07-2013 13:00:10.788 [main] INFO  main.App (App.java:60) 
Trying to print string!

19-07-2013 13:00:10.794 [main] INFO  main.App (App.java:61) 
Be aware!

19-07-2013 13:00:10.795 [main] INFO  main.App (App.java:63) 
String printed

19-07-2013 13:00:10.795 [main] DEBUG main.App (App.java:64) 
Program executed!
```

**Additional data**

```
Run #1 started at: 19-07-2013 13:00:10
Run #2 started at: 19-07-2013 13:10:58

Run #1 log file  : name-19-07-2013_13.10.58.log
Run #2 log file  : name.log
```

As you can see, the file name of the first run's log depends on when the second run is
started. I find that irritating  and misleading.

Comment: Where is the problem? The time in th file name is when the file was rolled out. After that no new messages are appended because the new messages are sent to the normal log file.

Comment: The problem is that when log4j2 copies the content of the old 'current' file, it should set the creation date of exact this file as timestamp and not some newer date, that has nothing to do with the contained data. At least I want to configure it that way. But I can't.

Comment: The date of the file is not independent of the content. All logging entries in the file are *before* the timestamp given in the file. This is because the `RollingFileAppender` renames your current log file to a file with timestamp (of the rolling) and then creates a new one where the new log entires are created.

Comment: Did you read my question completely? I know how the intrinsic mechanics work. My problem lies in changing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to configure any of the existing appenders to do what you want.

You could use the `FileAppender` but it doesn't roll over when it gets too big.

The `RollingFileAppender` will always write to `fileName` and move the content of this file into one with the supplied pattern *after* the conditions are met (so it will never create a file with the specified pattern and then write into it). That means, from your point of view, the timestamp of the file will always be after the last log entry in the file. This is by design.

To fix this issue, you have to write your own appender.

Comment: If you decide to write your own appender, please consider contributing it to log4j2 so others can use it as well.